# How to use the regexp for digits with an interactive search?

Tags: regular-expressions

For example, I have the following content in the buffer:

```
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```

To match the 4 numbers, I need the regular expression of `\d{4}`.
I would like to do the same in Emacs, when I press <kbd>C-s</kbd> and type the regexp.

When I'm looking in the documentation of Emacs regexp, many various regexp, Emacs own regexp, applications in Emacs Lisp, and so on, it's intensively documented.

I just want to have interactive search, type the regexp `\d{4}` and find the match. How could I apply that? The documentation gave no directly answer on this.

Comment: Press `C-M-s` and type `[0-9]{4}`. As far as I know that is the emacs-way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no `\d` in [Emacs regular
expressions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).
So, @Tobias's comment is (mostly) correct, except that you need to
escape the curly brackets.  Either of the following will work:

```
`C-M-s` => [0-9]\{4\}
`C-M-s` => [[:digit:]]\{4\}
```

Comment: Such a pity! I did verify the search including the backslash. I do not know why I missed the backslash in the comment. Maybe, it was the late hour. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dan and @Tobias but I'm wondering why Emacs don't have any application for 'regular' regexp's?

Comment: I know that the [visual-regexp-steriods package](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/) adds support for python and perl like regular expressions

Comment: @ReneFroger: don't know, sorry.  That sounds like a separate question and possibly a feature request.

Comment: @JulesTamagnan thanks for your answer, great package by the way!